# What is the proper way to avoid warning trailing constraint is missing on button inside the TableViewcell

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder

I want to have UI design like (Send Feedback Button)
[image: UI Send Feedback Button]

First I didn't add Trailing space (my thought was if I add trailing space and if the font got bigger, the text will get truncated, CMIIW)

So to avoid that, I set the trailing space to use "Standard Value", but when I used that and I clicked anywhere in the entire cell, the button got clicked.

So how to get rid of the trailing space warning, without making the entire TableCell clickable? (I just only want my text to be clickable).

Many thanks.

Comment: It is recommended that you have the trailing constraint so that your layout works correctly in a Right-to-left locale.  As long as you have the text field set to left aligned you should be able to simply add a trailing constraint to the margin of 0 and it won't affect your layout

Comment: @Paulw11 but when I did that, the entire table cell can be clicked. I don't want that behaviour happen in my app (wrong tap). btw it is a button, not a text field

Comment: You could try setting a trailing space constraint with a lower priority as suggested by @Yogi or you could add a placeholder transparent `UIView`

Comment: If I use lower priority for the trailing, then I need to add width constraint, isn't it? So the width constraint will override the trailing because of the priority?

Comment: You shouldn't need a width constraint, just set the horizontal content hugging priority a bit higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a trailing space constraint with a lower priority (i.e. < 1000). It won't give warning in case the constraint is broken.

I have attached a screenshot from my app for your reference.

Hope this helps[image: !]

Comment: then, I need to add width constraint? @Yogi

Comment: Nope. You won't have to.

Comment: thank you very much, I've tried it and it works!! When I try to bigger the font or make text longer, it will not truncated.

Answer (score 0):

if i am correct, you just want to keep the text tappable.
I think you should not give the height & width constraint to the button , it will manage the size according to the text. Just set the leading & vertical constraint to the content view. I hope it would help.